# Find Longest Path in Graph

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have been trying hard to find out longest path in a complex network. I have been through many questions in StackOverflow and Internet, but none could help me. I have written a CQL as

```
start n=node(*)
match p = (n)-[:LinkTo*1..]->(m)
with n,MAX(length(p)) as L
match p = (n)-[:LinkTo*1..]->(m)
where length(p) = L
return p,L
```

I don't get any solution. Neo4J would keep running for the answer, and I also tried executing it in Neo4J Cloud Hosting. I didn't any solution even there, but got an error 
"Error undefined-undefined"
I am in dire need of a solution. The result for this answer will help me complete my project. So, anyone please help me in correcting the query.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure you're doing what you think you're doing. This query finds, for every node n, the longest paths from each n to some node m. Your output will be one path for every node in your entire db, and its length. That is an extreme query for any moderate to large db. Is that really what you want, or do you only one the single largest path in your entire db?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well for one you're doing a highly expensive operation twice when you only have to do it once.

Additionally, you are returning one path per every single node in your database, at least (as there may be multiple paths for a node that are the longest paths available for that node). But from your question it sounds like you want the single largest path in the graph, not one each for every single node.

We can also improve your match by only performing the longest-path match on nodes that are at the head of the path, and not somewhere in the middle.

Maybe try this one?

```
match (n)
where (n)-[:LinkTo]->() and not ()-[:LinkTo]->(n)
match p = (n)-[:LinkTo*1..]->(m)
return p, length(p) as L
order by L desc
limit 1
```

Comment: I want to consider complete graph. The reason why I wanted to return a longest path is that, it answer 5 more questions. 1. Length of Path 2. Check for Source Node presence 3. Probability of adjacent nodes getting affected by source node. 4. Time taken to affect 5. Best node to be isolated to prevent further spreading.

Comment: Can I reach you over mail? Please.

Answer (score 5):

The problem you're trying to solve is NP-hard. On small sparse graphs a brute-force approach such as the one suggested by InverseFalcon may succeed in reasonable time, but on any reasonably large and/or densely connected graph, you will quickly run into both time and space problems.

If you have a *weighted* graph, you can find the longest path between 2 nodes by negating all the edge-weights, and running a shortest weighted path algorithm over the modified graph. However if you want to find the longest path in the entire graph, you are effectively trying to solve the [Travelling Salesman Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Travelling_salesman_problem), but with -ve edge weights. You can't do that with Cypher.

If your graph is unweighted, I'd find an easier problem, or see if you can convert your graph to a weighted one and tackle it as described above. Alternatively, see if you can frame your requirements in such a way that you don't need to find a longest path.

Comment: In my graph, all the edges have common weight of 1. So, should I consider it or avoid using it?

Comment: As long as every edge weight is non-zero you can find the shortest path between any 2 nodes.  But if you want to solve TSP however (and I think you do), shortest path algorithms will not help. Take a look at the Bellman-Hard-Karp algorithm instead.