# Iterate over nodes in neo4j

Tags: graph, neo4j, cypher

I have a graph with 2137 different paths, not connected to each other. The nodes in each path are numbered by a property, "Isnad", where Isnad = 1,2,3....2137. I want to return the lengths of all 2137 paths.

```
match(n:Narrator)
where n.Isnad = "1"
return count(n)
```

Now this works for me but I want to iterate for "Isnad" so I get the count for all 2137 paths instead of just one. Any suggestions?
In pseudocode, it would be like:

```
for(int i = 1 to 2137)
    match(n:Narrator)
    where n.Isnad = i
    return count(n)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`range`](http://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/3.2/cypher/functions/list/#functions-range) and [`UNWIND`](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/clauses/unwind/#query-unwind):

```
unwind range(1, 2137) AS i
match p=(n:Narrator)-[*]->(m)
where toInteger(n.Isnad) = i
  and not ()-[]->(n)
  and not (m)-[]->()
return n.Isnad, length(p)
limit 10
```

Note that we are looking for the longest paths. This is expressed in the `WHERE` condition: the first node of the path should not have a preceding node (`not ()-[]->(n)`), while the last node of the path should not have a succeeding node (`not (m)-[]->()`) -- see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41797268/3580502).

I included the `limit 10` line so that the computation and returning the result will not freeze the server or the web user interface. If the query seems okay, remove `limit 10` and see if it still works. When embedded to a client application, it can scale to more results as the rendering of the web UI will no longer be a bottleneck.

Comment: I'm sorry, I think you misunderstood my question. My code works fine for just one "Isnad". I need a query which can iterate my Isnad from 1 to 2,3,4 and so on and return length for every Isnad. 
Something like this:
for(i :1 to 2137)
     return length(p) where n.Isnad = i;

Comment: Thankyou, this is almost correct, except that it is repeating this for every node in a path. For example, if I have 3 nodes in one path, it is returning the length from all 3 instead of just the first node. Here's my query and result: https://ibb.co/nbTYtw
(I had to edit your's a bit because for my nodes, Isnad is not their only property. Also, the Isnad property has stored the numbers as Strings so I have first converted them to Integer) :)

Comment: Other than Narrator, do you have any node labels that the query could use? What about relationship types?

Comment: In the meantime, I found the problem with the query -- here, we are interested in the length of the _longest path_ and not all paths that start from a particular node.

Comment: Works perfectly! Thank you so much for your time and patience :)